# Generating Bearer Token for AutoML, Computer Vision from Python Library

Tags: python, google-api, google-cloud-platform, automl, google-cloud-automl

Based on this [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth) I can generate the token for [Computer Vision API request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/object-localizer) by calling this in terminal `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`. However, I am going to call the request from my python code and I try to generate from Python code, something like below...

The code is based on [this documentation page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

```
with open( environ.get(KEY_ENV_VARIABLE) ) as f:
    key = json.load(f)

iat = time.time()
exp = iat + 3600
payload = {
    'iss': key.get('client_email'),
    'sub': key.get('client_email'),
    'aud': 'https://vision.googleapis.com/google.cloud.automl_v1beta1',
    'iat': iat,
    'exp': exp
}
additional_headers = { "kid": key.get("private_key_id") }
signed_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, key.get("private_key"), headers=additional_headers, algorithm='HS256')
return signed_jwt.decode('utf-8')
```

It does generate the token however it is different in terms of length, compared to the token generated by `gcloud` tool.

I know that the easiest and quick dirty fix would be calling `os.system('gcloud auth application-default print-access-token')`. However, I do not want to do the dirty way if possible and want to generate the token in correct way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#iam-service-account-keys-create-python) to download a service account. After you get a key, you'll want to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the file path of the key.